# How can I show root directory as well as external mounted drives like USB, CD-Rom with Qtreeview on Linux OS?

Tags: linux

I just want to show root directory and external mounted drivers (USB, CD) if available on Linux as multiple QTreeViews. As following

/
USB
CD

But, for now I can only show external mounted drivers under root directory.

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller pieces, as ever.

Comment: Please show us this piece of code that already works.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build your own QAbstractItemModel (and not use QFileSystemModel) as QFileSystemModel will show you the tree files as they are.

If you are a beginner I strongly advise you to think differently your user interface as making tree model is not an easy task.

Or you can use several QFileSystemModel that would be initialized with different paths with QFileSystemModel::setRootPath :

- one the VFS root
- one for /media (you can even extract all mount point here `/proc/mounts` or use the /sys interface)

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

External drives can not be viewed on Linux with QFileSystemModel

from Qt Manual:

> QDir::Drives  List disk drives (ignored under Unix).